# Swipe to delete row without having to hit the delete button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I know how the swipe to delete function works, though I'm not quite sure how to make it so that rather than having the delete button come up to delete I'd rather make it so that the cell is deleted upon swiping the cell to left or right.

Here's where I make the cell register the left swipe gesture to the left:

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

And here is the method for the selector:

```
- (void)swipeLeft:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)gestureRecognizer.view;
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    }
}
```

Now it works just fine when deleting cells from UITableview; however, I need an animation to show the cell moving to the left a certain distance and then deleting. I do not what a delete button.

edit: Here's the delete row with animation:

```
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

This deletes just fine, but can I make it so that it creates like a fade animation or can I modify this so after after swiping a specified distance will commit the delete?

Comment: do you want to do something like whats done in the Mailbox app for deleting mails?

Comment: Right, but rather than "More"  and "Archive" coming up I want it to just automatically deleting rather than having to confirm by pressing either of those buttons.

Comment: So when a user accidentally does a swipe motion you want to delete the data with no chance to abort? Not a good idea. But if you really want to then don't use the standard swipe-to-delete. Add your own swipe gesture to  each cell.

Comment: Right so that's what I've done already, but once they swipe it just deletes without any type of animation. I want to see the entire cell move to the left along with all of its contents.

Comment: If it deletes with no animation then you chose to do it that way. Delete the row with animation instead. Post your deletion code if you need help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a custom swipe I had made for a static table view, however should work for a dynamic table view. It will allow you to swipe to a set max x postition. If the user releases it will animate back to the original location.

I've tweaked the code so it should work with a dynamic cell. But not tested yet.

Add this local var

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat changeX;
```

Just connect a pan GR to the storyboard and connect to this action.

```
- (IBAction)dragCell:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint swipeLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];
    UITableViewCell*swipedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        self.changeX = swipeLocation.x;
    }
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGFloat maxRight = 100; // change this to increase distance of hit point
        CGFloat newX = swipeLocation.x - self.changeX; // relative from first touch location
        if (newX <= 0) newX = 0;
        if (newX >= maxRight) {
            newX = maxRight;
            NSLog(@"Hit the point where I'll allow delete");
        }
        swipedCell.frame = CGRectMake(newX, swipedCell.frame.origin.y, swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.size.height);
    }

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            swipedCell.frame = CGRectMake(0, swipedCell.frame.origin.y, swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.size.height);
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            //
        }];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesomeness! I do have one question about what self.changeX is exactly?

Comment: Okay, I see it's CGFloat changeX (delta) in order to create the difference of the two for newX. Strangely enough this works really well! Bravo! For some reason it doesn't delete the cell I'm dragging, though. It's the bottom of the stack it deletes, but that's all on my end here. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't call reloadData. It kills the animation.